# how to get phone ringtone type name in android programmatically instead of getting ringtone id

Tags: android, ringtone

how to get phone ringtone type name in android programmatically.I can get only the ringtone id(`://media/internal/audio/media/53`).How can get ringtone `name(panic)` instead of `id(53)`.Please help me.

I used following code to get the ringtone name :

```
Uri mUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI); 
Cursor mCursor = query(mUri, null, null,null, null); 
mCursor.moveToFirst(); 
String ringtoneName= Cursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("title")); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone"+ringtoneName+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But it shows null pointer exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I got the solution using below code :**

**Inside onActivityResult:**

```
Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
Ringtone r=RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri); 
String ringToneName=r.getTitle(this));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone Name : +ringtonename+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But it will show exception in emulator because there is no ringtone in emulator so execute this in mobile

Comment: i am still getting id in `ringtonename` ,any solution?

Comment: @NikunjParadva did you get any solution for id issue? I'm also getting id for ringtone title instead of title itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines.  Title should give you the title of the media

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("content://media/internal/audio/media/53"); 

Cursor mCursor = query(mUri, null, null,null, null);
mCursor.movetoFirst();
//use below ringtoneName to get the title of the ringtone
String ringtoneName= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
```

Comment: i guess the columnindex might be wrong. Try to change the column index.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html plz check this                                               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode==999)                    {
    Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    
Cursor mCursor = query(uri, null, null,null, null);
    
String title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
   
if (uri != null) {
ringTonePath = uri.toString();
   }

  }

Comment: what error are you getting. And edit your own question rather than editing the answer

Comment: Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
if (uri != null)  
ringTonePath = uri.toString();

in ringTonePath i can get only id not the name of ringtone

Comment: I am a beginner to android.plz help me i cant understand

Comment: check the value of variable title not ringtonepath

Comment: How to check the value of title

Comment: Wherever you want the name use title

Comment: Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);      if (uri != null) {
    ringTonePath = uri.toString(); } In ringTonePath i got only url with id

Comment: i have tried ur edit thing but it shows error.may b i make a mistake

Comment: Uri mUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

Cursor mCursor = query(mUri, null, null,null, null);
mCursor.moveToFirst();
   //use below ringtoneName to get the title of the ringtone
String ringtoneName= Cursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone"+ringtoneName+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                               It shows null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

A Quick Way:

```
Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
String songTitle = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this);
```